# setting JSONReadingOptions in AFJSONRequestOperation

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, nsjsonserialization

I have inherited `AFHTTPClient` & I registered the `AFJSONRequestOperation` class as request handler as follow

```
- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
    [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
    self.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;

    return self;
}
```

However, I need the parsed json into Mutable object. I found there was a JSONReadingOptions property on `AFJSONRequestOperation` but I couldn't figure out how to set it since I am directly working with `AFHTTPClient`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple.

1. Create subclass of AFJSONRequestOperation.
2. Change this in subclass of AFHTTPClient:

```c
 [__instance registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
```

to this:

```c
[__instance registerHTTPOperationClass:[CustomClassJSONRequestOperation class]];
```

in CustomClassJSONRequestOperation.m just write this:

```c
- (id)responseJSON {
    [self setJSONReadingOptions: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers | NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];    
    return [super responseJSON];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of my requests was failing and returned the error:

> JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow
>   fragments not set.

To set the JSONReadingOptions I had to subclass `AFJSONRequestOperation` and then set the property on the instance returned from the static factory method.

```
+ (instancetype)JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest
                                        success:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON))success
                                        failure:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON))failure
{
    AFJSONRequestOperation *requestOperation = [super JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:urlRequest success:success failure:failure];
    requestOperation.JSONReadingOptions = NSJSONReadingAllowFragments;
    return (MyRequestSubclass *)requestOperation;
}
```

And then, in your client set your subclass as the HTTPOperationClass when you initialize the sharedClient

```
[__instance registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
```

... Then again, it turned out that the api I was hitting happened to be down, so it was returning an html error page...

Long story short, before you bother, make sure that the response isn't just poorly formed, and that it exists in the first place.

Comment: the Response is well formed and works fine. I just needed to have Mutable Objects instead of Immutable ones. So what I really did was that I created "NSMutableDictionary" using the initialization methods.